# Unable to populate a ListView with data from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to populate `ListView` with data from SQLite database. I've checked countless tutorials, went exploring Stack Overflow, and although a lot of people have a similar problem as me, the more I look into why a code doesn't work, the more I can't find a problem. I must be missing something major in the way I've approached this problem, so posting this question is truly my last resort. Any help would be appreciated.

Before I continue, I'm not asking for anyone to code for me, I've been stuck on this problem for hours now and I'm not getting anywhere.

Thus far, I've created a `Fragment` class:

```
public class RecordsListFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {


    public static final String ARGUMENT_ITEM_ID = "records_list";
    Activity activity;
    ListView recordsListView;
    ArrayList<Records> records;

    RecordsListAdapter recordsListAdapter;
    RecordsDAO recordsDAO;

    private GetRecordsTask task;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
    recordsDAO = new RecordsDAO(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_records_list, container, false);
    findViewsById(view);

    task = new GetRecordsTask(activity);
    task.execute((Void) null);

    recordsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    recordsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    return view;
    }

    private void findViewsById(View view) {
    recordsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_records);
    recordsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    recordsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Records record = (Records) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    if (records != null) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putParcelable("selectedRecord,", record);

        CustomRecordsDialogFragment customRecordsDialogFragment = new CustomRecordsDialogFragment();
        customRecordsDialogFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        customRecordsDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), CustomRecordsDialogFragment.ARGUMENT_ITEM_ID);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Records records = (Records) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    recordsDAO.deleteRecord(records);
    recordsListAdapter.remove(records);

    return true;
    }

    public class GetRecordsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Records>> {

    private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;

    ArrayList<Records> recordsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public GetRecordsTask(Activity context) {
        this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Records> empList) {
        if (activityWeakRef.get() != null && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
            records = empList;
            if (empList != null) {
                if (empList.size() != 0) {
                    recordsListAdapter = new RecordsListAdapter(activity, empList);
                    recordsListView.setAdapter(recordsListAdapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "No records in the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Records> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        recordsArrayList = recordsDAO.getRecords();
        return recordsArrayList;
    }
    }

    public void updateView() {
    task = new GetRecordsTask(activity);
    task.execute((Void) null);
    }

    public void onResume() {
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    super.onResume();
    }
}
```

and an `Adapter` class

```
public class RecordsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Records>{

    private Context context;
    List<Records> records;

    private static final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public RecordsListAdapter(Context context, List<Records> records) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, records);
    this.context = context;
    this.records = records;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
    TextView recordsIdTxt, recordsDescriptionTxt, recordsDateTxt, recordsStartTxt, recordsFinishTxt;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return records.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Records getItem(int position) {
    return records.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.recordsIdTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_record_id);
        holder.recordsDescriptionTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_record_description);
        holder.recordsDateTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_record_date);
        holder.recordsStartTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_record_start);
        holder.recordsFinishTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_record_finish);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Records records = (Records) getItem(position);
    holder.recordsIdTxt.setText(String.format("%d", records.getId()));
    holder.recordsDescriptionTxt.setText(records.getName());
    holder.recordsDateTxt.setText(formatter.format(records.getDateofRecord()));
    holder.recordsStartTxt.setText(records.getStart());
    holder.recordsFinishTxt.setText(records.getFinish());

    return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Records record) {
    records.add(record);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.add(record);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Records record) {
    records.remove(record);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.remove(record);
    }
}
```

but nothing is displayed in the `ListView`. Now, I'm not getting any errors, but I am seeing the `No records in the database` toast message appearing even after filling the form and saving it. Fragment where saving records happens returns `Record saved` + database is filling up, I've checked the database file in `/data/data` and I've used DB Browser for SQLite to double check on that.

So why is `empList.size()` then `=0`, if there is data in the database I h

Again, all I'm asking for is someone to help me understand what's going on and where am I wrong.

**Edit 1:** This is the method I'm using to retrieve all the records from the database:

```
public ArrayList<Records> getRecords() {
    ArrayList<Records> records = new ArrayList<Records>();

    String query = "SELECT " + RECORDS_ID_WITH_PREFIX + ", "
            + RECORDS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + " ,"
            + DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.STARTINGHOUR + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.FINISHINGHOUR + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.COMMENTS + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONS_ID + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.TAGS_ID + ", " + LOCATIONS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + ", " + TAGS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + " FROM "
            + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORDS + " rec, " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOCATIONS + " loc, " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAGS + " tg "
            + " WHERE rec." + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONS_ID + " = loc." + DatabaseHelper.ID + " AND "
            + DatabaseHelper.TAGS_ID + " = tg." + DatabaseHelper.ID;

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Records records1 = new Records();
        records1.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        records1.setName(cursor.getString(1));

        try {
            records1.setDateofRecord(formatter.parse(cursor.getString(2)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            records1.setDateofRecord(null);
        }

        records1.setStart(cursor.getString(3));
        records1.setFinish(cursor.getString(4));
        records1.setComments(cursor.getString(5));

        Locations locations = new Locations();
        locations.setId(cursor.getInt(6));
        locations.setName(cursor.getString(7));

        Tags tags = new Tags();
        tags.setId(cursor.getInt(8));
        tags.setName(cursor.getString(9));

        records1.setLocations(locations);
        records1.setTags(tags);
        records.add(records1);
    }
    return records;
}
```

**Edit 2:** the solution to my problem was trivial. The `WHERE` statement seemed to filter out the data from the database, which is why I haven't been able to see anything in the `Log.d`. Simply replace

```
    String query = "SELECT " + RECORDS_ID_WITH_PREFIX + ", "
            + RECORDS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + " ,"
            + DatabaseHelper.KEY_CREATED_AT + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.STARTINGHOUR + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.FINISHINGHOUR + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.COMMENTS + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONS_ID + ", "
            + DatabaseHelper.TAGS_ID + ", " + LOCATIONS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + ", " + TAGS_NAME_WITH_PREFIX + " FROM "
            + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORDS + " rec, " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_LOCATIONS + " loc, " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAGS + " tg "
            + " WHERE rec." + DatabaseHelper.LOCATIONS_ID + " = loc." + DatabaseHelper.ID + " AND "
            + DatabaseHelper.TAGS_ID + " = tg." + DatabaseHelper.ID;
```

with

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORDS;
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the database insert code, not the retrieval

Comment: I've updated my question so that you can see a method used to retrieve records from the database. Is it of any good?

Comment: Before `return records;`, add a `Log.d` line that outputs that list as a string. Then run your app and watch the logcat output

Comment: I've added `Log.d("What is happening?", String.valueOf(records));` which returns `06-10 19:50:01.361 29049-29081/com.example.benignfella.workorganizer D/What is happening?: []`, apparently nothing gets added?

Comment: Log the query you are executing and run it in your DB browser. Maybe your query is not returning any results. Sometimes the error jumps at sight when you look at the query.

Comment: Either nothing is added, or the WHERE statement filtered out all the data. At least now you know the adapter isn't necessarily the problem

Comment: IT WORKS! AFTER SO MANY HOURS! Dear @cricket_007 just gave the best advice possible. Will post the solution to my question. FROM THE BOTTOM OF MY HEART, THANK YOU!!!